# How to receive AJAX (json) response in a divs with same class name individually?

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, html

I've been getting crazier day after day with this, I can't find an answer, I've spent like 100h+ with this... I hope someone could help me out!

UPDATE:
So to make myself more clear on this issue and be able to get help from others, I basically have 3 containers named "main-container" they all have 3 containers as childs all with the same class name, and when I submit the button, I trigger an ajax function to load the JSON strings comming from php into the child divs, the problem is that I get the 3 "main_containers" to load the ajax at the same time, **I only want to load the ajax if I press the button of each "main_container" individually.**

I've been using jquery and vanilla JS as well but seems I just can't get it done!

This is how I currently trigger the button with jquery:

```
$('.trigger_button_inside_divs').click(my_ajax_function);
```

And this is how my ajax looks like:

```
function my_ajax_function(){
$.ajax({
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: 'POST',
        url: test.php,
        success: function(data) {

     $('.div_to_render_JSON_1').html(data.PHP_JSON_1_RECEIVED);
     $('.div_to_render_JSON_2').html(data.PHP_JSON_2_RECEIVED);
     $('.div_to_render_JSON_3').html(data.PHP_JSON_3_RECEIVED);

        }
    });
}
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="main_container">
    <div class="my_div">
     //div_to_render_JSON_1
    </div>

        <div class="my_div">
          //div_to_render_JSON_2
        </div>

   <div class="my_div">
   //div_to_render_JSON_3
   </div>

   <button class="trigger_ajax_function_btn">Click to load ajax</button> //this btn loads ajax into the div class "my_div"
</div>



<div class="main_container">
    <div class="my_div">
     //div_to_render_JSON_1
    </div>

        <div class="my_div">
          //div_to_render_JSON_2
        </div>

   <div class="my_div">
   //div_to_render_JSON_3
   </div>

   <button class="trigger_ajax_function_btn">Click to load ajax</button> //this btn loads ajax into the div class "my_div"
</div>



<div class="main_container">
    <div class="my_div">
     //div_to_render_JSON_1
    </div>

        <div class="my_div">
          //div_to_render_JSON_2
        </div>

   <div class="my_div">
   //div_to_render_JSON_3
   </div>

   <button class="trigger_ajax_function_btn">Click to load ajax</button> //this btn loads ajax into the div class "my_div"
</div>
```

So in conclusion, each of those 6 "divs" has a button that triggers an function containing my ajax to render inside that particular div. But what I get is that every time I click that triggering button, I get the ajax to render in all of the 6 divs, instead of render on each particular div only when I click its particular button.

Thanks a lot people, I really hope to get this done!
Cheers.

**PD:**
This is something a programmer did to achieve what I'm trying to achieve but I just can't figure out **what in this code is that is making possible clicking 1 button and affect THAT html element** , even though they all have the same class.

```
(function(){
$("form input[type=submit]").click(function() {
    $("input[type=submit]", $(this).parents("form")).removeAttr("clicked");
    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
});



var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var el;




function SetDataInTheForm()
{
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.response)
    var pt=0
    var ct=0
    var gt=0

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(el.querySelectorAll(".test"),function(e,i){
        e.innerHTML=resp[i].name
    })
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(el.querySelectorAll(".p"),function(e,i){
        e.innerHTML=parseFloat(resp[i].p).toFixed(0)
        pt+=parseFloat(resp[i].p)
    })
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(el.querySelectorAll(".c"),function(e,i){
        e.innerHTML=parseFloat(resp[i].c).toFixed(0)
        ct+=parseFloat(resp[i].c)
    })
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(el.querySelectorAll(".g"),function(e,i){
        e.innerHTML=parseFloat(resp[i].g).toFixed(0)
        gt+=parseFloat(resp[i].g)
    })


    el.querySelector(".wtp").innerHTML=parseFloat(resp[0].total).toFixed(0)+" "+resp[0].unit
    el.querySelector(".wtc").innerHTML=parseFloat(resp[1].total).toFixed(0)+" "+resp[1].unit
    el.querySelector(".wtg").innerHTML=parseFloat(resp[2].total).toFixed(0)+" "+resp[2].unit

    el.querySelector(".pt").innerHTML=pt.toFixed(0)
    el.querySelector(".ct").innerHTML=ct.toFixed(0)
    el.querySelector(".gt").innerHTML=gt.toFixed(0)
}




function HandleSubmit(e)
{
    el=e.currentTarget
    e.preventDefault();
    xhr.open("POST","/url_here.php",true)
    xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    xhr.onload=SetDataInTheForm
    var button=e.currentTarget.querySelector("input[type=submit][clicked=true]")
    button.removeAttribute("clicked")
    xhr.send($("#"+e.currentTarget.id).serialize()+"&"+button.getAttribute("name")+"=on")
}



[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("._form_"),function(form){
    form.addEventListener("submit",HandleSubmit,false);
})


})()
```

Comment: Include your HTML. And if you can put the whole thing in a functional stack snippet, you'll get a lot more traction on this.

Comment: Does your divs contain different classes? You are currently writing your response to a class rather than an Id in your ajax callback

Comment: use $(this).html(data.PHP_JSON_RECEIVED) instead of $('.div_container_to_render_JSON').html(data.PHP_JSON_RECEIVED);

Comment: thanks people, I updated my answer with the hope to make myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies people. I finally figured it out after days of hard work, it was something really simple.. here's the answer:

```
$('.trigger_button_inside_divs').click(my_ajax_function);


var thisButton = $(this);
var thisDiv = thisButton.closest(".main_container"); 




 function my_ajax_function(){
$.ajax({
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: 'POST',
        url: test.php,
        success: function(data) {

     thisDiv.find('.div_to_render_JSON_1').html(data.PHP_JSON_1_RECEIVED);
     thisDiv.find('.div_to_render_JSON_2').html(data.PHP_JSON_2_RECEIVED);
     thisDiv.find('.div_to_render_JSON_3').html(data.PHP_JSON_3_RECEIVED);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `$('.div_container_to_render_JSON')` is a new selector that selects all elements with a class `div_container_to_render_JSON`. What you want to happen is figuring out where that click came from, and find the corresponding `div_container_to_render_JSON`.

Luckily for you, a jQuery click handler sets the `this` keyword to the HTMLElement where the click was captured. You can use this to get the parent element.

```
$('.your-button').on('click', function () {
  const myButton = $(this);

  $.ajax({
    // ...
    success (data) {
      myButton.parent().html(data.PHP_JSON_RECEIVED);

      // or if you need to find a parent further up in the chain
      // myButton.parents('.div_container_to_render_JSON').html(data.PHP_JSON_RECEIVED);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, but seems that ain't solving the problem. I updated my question hope to get myself more clear, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your class selector is indeed selecting all your divs at the same time.

Solution, set identifiers for your divs as such:

```
<div class="my_div" id="my_div_1">
```

and then you can use those id's to fill in the data:

```
$('#my_div_1').html(data.PHP_JSON_1_RECEIVED);
```

and repeat for your 6 divs (notice the change from class selector '.' to identifier selector '#')

Comment: but this way I will need to repeat a lot of code, since I have 6 "main-containers" in my html, meaning, I will need to make 6 different ajax calls for each and every "main-container".

Comment: Not at all, get the data in one ajax call the same way you are doing it, just put it in the right place using the correct identifiers...
Before you had:  $('.div_to_render_JSON_1').html(data.PHP_JSON_1_RECEIVED);
$('.div_to_render_JSON_2').html(data.PHP_JSON_2_RECEIVED);
...
Now use:
$('#my_div_1').html(data.PHP_JSON_1_RECEIVED);
$('#my_div_2').html(data.PHP_JSON_2_RECEIVED);
...